# In freecad, how do you copy a sketch geometry from one plane to another?

Tags: cad, technical-drawing

I'm using FreeCAD, and I would like to copy all the geometry in a 2D sketch to another plane. So you have a 2D drawing on XY, and you want the same geometry to be copied to XZ. I can't seem to find an good way to do this.

One way I have tried is to copy the whole sketch, create a cube, and then map the geometry of the new sketch copy to the cube object face. It's quite a clunky method however and I doubt it's the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Duplicate is ambiguous. Copy the geometry, but have all new dimensions driving this? Or have linked geometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the carbon-copy feature of Sketcher WB:

1. Create an empty new sketch in the plane you want.
2. On the Model tab, make the sketch you want to copy visible (click and hit spacebar).
3. In the sketch, rotate if necessary to view the to-be-copied sketch.
4. Click on the carbon-copy tool in the toolbar.
5. Hold ctrl-alt and click anywhere on the to-be-copied sketch.

You may find this helpful:
https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=21762